# connection error in signalR in Vuex on VueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, signalr

I'm trying to connect signalR using the Vuex store in VueJS, but when it is time to connect subscriptions, I get an error

I break the repository into several files

store index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import SignalR from './modules/signalR'


Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = () =>
  new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      signalR: SignalR
    }
  });

export default store
```

SignalR main connection file signalR/index.js

```
const signalR = require('@aspnet/signalr')
const Cookie = process.client ? require("js-cookie") : undefined;

export default {
  state: {
    connection: null
  },
```

I declare actions which I cause through dispatch in the main component of the application

```
  actions: {
    connectSignalR(context, data) {
      var token = Cookie.get("authToken");
      console.log('signalR', token)  

      context.state.connection == null ? context.state = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(context.getters.base_signalr + "/notification",
      { accessTokenFactory: () => token }).build()
      : false

      let startedPromise = null
      function start() {
        startedPromise = context.state.connection.start()
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Failed to connect with hun', error)
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            setTimeout(() => start().then(resolve).catch(reject), 5000))
        })
        return startedPromise
      }

      context.state.connection.onclose(() => start())

      //context.state.connection.connectionSlow(function() {
      //  console.log('slow connection...');
      //});

      context.state.connection.on('support', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })

      start()
    }
  }
}
```

error

```
TypeError: context.state.connection.connectionSlow is not a function
at Store.connectSignalR
```

or

```
TypeError: context.state.connection.on is not a function
at Store.connectSignalR
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I'd recommend storing your connection object in the state, or trying to register callbacks in an action. I've found that it's a lot easier to host your connection object in a plugin. If you'd still like to integrate Vuex you can reference your store in the plugin and vice versa...

Create a plugin:

```
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
import store from '../store';

const SignalRPlugin = {
    install(Vue) {
        // make your signalR connection
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .withUrl("hubUrl")
            .build();

        // register callbacks
        connection.on("DoStuff", () => {
            store.dispatch('DoTheStuff', true);
        });

        //Anything you want to expose outside of the plugin should be prefixed Vue.prototype.$
        Vue.prototype.$sendSomething = function(something){
            connection.send("Incoming", something);
        }
    }
}

export default SignalRPlugin;
```

In your actions add your plugin at the top...

```
import SignalRPlugin from '../plugins/signalRPlugin';
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(SignalRPlugin);
let app = new Vue();
```

And then you can use your plugin:
`app.$sendSomething('My super important message');`

Comment: I like this plugin approach, how do you add the JWT token later? I only have a part of hub connection where it needs to be authenticated.

Comment: @JohanVanWambeke I don't use JWT, but unfortunately it looks like SignalR currently has some limitations with respect to bearer tokens. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13642

Comment: const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("/hubs/notifications", { accessTokenFactory: () => token })
      .withAutomaticReconnect() 
      .build();     where token is your jwt token string

Comment: why would not use `Vue.store` but imported store? It feels like you might having two stores in app context.... right?